# Chose EFI boot on Mac but no Black & White screen to edit boot entry

Tags: boot, command-line, nomodeset, moklistrt

I am new to this but I wanted to try Ubuntu on my Macbook Pro (2012). i followed a couple of similar instruction on the internet but when I got to the 'edit boot entry' to add "nomodeset" after "quietsplash" before installing Ubuntu I was not able to do this.
I carried on with the install anyway and all seems to be working however I briefly get a message on startup saying "Failed to set MokListRT: Invalid Parameter. Could not create MokListRT: Invalid Parameter. Importing MOK states has failed:import_mok_state() failed: Invalid Parameter Continuing boot since secure mode is disabled_
Is this because I was unable to edit the boot entry and can I do this from Terminal still?
Any help would be greatly appreciated please, I have no idea of course why the boot entry should be edited like this as I am new to this but not sure how to start from scratch as I overwrote the MAC OS. Can I try to reboot from the usb again or do I need to flash Ubuntu OS on it again? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR

---

`MokListRT` has nothing to do with `nomodeset`. It is a list of all [UEFI Secure Boot](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot) keys that your Mac’s firmware **trusts**. Since Secure Boot is disabled anyways (*`Continuing boot since Secure Mode is disabled`*, as it says), this error is actually **completely harmless** — other than probably being annoying.

##### To get rid of the error:

1. Head over to [Rod Smith’s](https://www.rodsbooks.com/) repository of [common keys](https://sourceforge.net/p/refind/code/ci/master/tree/keys/) and download [Microsoft’s third-party key](https://sourceforge.net/p/refind/code/ci/master/tree/keys/microsoft-uefica-public.cer)
2. Run `sudo mokutil -i /path/to/downloaded/file`. Remember the password you enter here.
3. On rebooting the Mac, it *should* ask you for the password you had entered previously.
4. *Víola!* Now you shouldn’t see that error anymore. The password was just temporary, to make sure you were the same person between steps.

These steps are from [Rod Smith’s website](https://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#mokutil). He’s the creator of `gpt-fdisk`, and the Hermione Granger of disks, booting, and EFI.

#### MOKs

---

*Machine Owner Keys* are signatures that the firmware trusts, and will allow to boot. Of course, if Secure Boot is disabled, then any boot-loader will be given the go-ahead. Ever since BootCamp, Apple does hard-code Mac firmware with Microsoft’s public key — the one they use to sign the Windows boot-loader. But till date (as of 2020 Intel Macs), **they do not pre-install** the key that Microsoft uses to sign **third-party software**, like GRUB in this case. This is why your Mac refuses to add GRUB stuff to the `MokListRT` with all that drama, and why I — with my 2019 MBP — still have to disable Secure Boot to install Ubuntu.

**N.B.:** Macs have always had their own EFI, only conforming in *majority* to the general UEFI specification. I really hope the `mokutil` acrobatics work, but the 2012 MBP — why, even a 2020 (Intel) one — might just plain refuse to add any other keys into its list.

#### `nomodeset`

---

This is really just a kernel argument to prevent the kernel from loading-in hardware-specific graphics. Without context, I’m not entirely sure why you would *need* to do it, but I see no harm. If you’re experiencing any graphics-related issues, here’s how you can add that in (and **no, you don’t need to do any wiping!**):

1. `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` (replace `gedit` with your favourite text-editor).
2. Find a line that says `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=...`. If there isn’t one, make one.
3. Replace the right-hand-side (`...`) to `"quiet splash nomodeset"`. (Just add `nomodeset` to the quoted list, if that was your sole objective. Btw, the presence of the option `quiet` hides the boot-up log output, and `splash` shows the familiar Ubuntu boot-up logo "splash screen".)

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you MarbleMuffin for taking the time to answer my query and with all the additional information I really appreciate it. I will try the above when I get home.